# Telethon delete_messages doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: python, message, telegram, telethon

Help: Relatively new to telethon and was having issue with `delete_messages()`function.  It "seems" to do nothing for me...

Initially I am getting the message id from send_message, from the return object's id value.  It returns values like 1, 2, etc.  Not sure this is the message id though.

I send it to `delete_messages` as `delete_messages(channel, [id])`

I get the channel (It's a private channel) from:

```
def resolve_channel_id(self, name):
    try:
        if name in self.__channel_ids:
            return self.__channel_ids[name]

        channel_id = self.client(ResolveUsernameRequest(name))
        self.__channel_ids[name] = channel_id
        return channel_id

    # except UserNameNotOccupiedError as err:
    except Exception as err:
        # try for private channel
        chatinvite = self.client(CheckChatInviteRequest(name))
        channel_id = chatinvite.chat.id
        access_hash_channel = chatinvite.chat.access_hash
        channel_id = InputChannel(channel_id, access_hash_channel)
        self.__channel_ids[name] = channel_id
        return channel_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this example is useful for friends :‌

by this code, if a message with a `Hello` text is sent to a group with ID `-1001300989487`, that text will be deleted.

```
import logging


from telethon import TelegramClient, events

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

api_id = XXXXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
phone_number = '+989XXXXXXXX'

################################################

client = TelegramClient('session_name',
                    api_id,
                    api_hash, 
                    )


@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=(-1001300989487)))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if 'hello' in event.raw_text:
        await event.delete()


client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()

print('finish')
```

Answer (score 0):

Works by updating to latest telethon: 1.0.3, and following documentation... https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/basic/asyncio-magic.html